# Measuring time spent watching a video?

Tags: javascript, video, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm building my own Video sharing web site and I want to get for each video - estimated watch time.

What is the best approach to get such measument as the user can just close your page any moment.

Sending requests any 10 secounds of video playback, seems to me as really bad solution ?

I couldn't find any html5 players offering such features.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact, that most analytic tracking system do use such kind of measurement (i.e.: every 10sec). This is indeed comming from the flash era. Another typical measurement is to track start, first quartile, half, thrid quartile and end, which is typical for advertisment tracking.

The best thing to use is the so called played property: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#dom-media-played

Comment: The problem with this approach is that if I replay the video in a previously played segment, for example if I restart the video in the segment [0..8] in second 4, played will not create a new segment, and it will continue counting in that same segement.

For example, if I restart in 4, and continue playing until 13, the segment [0..8] will become [0..13].

This makes sense given that the played property tells us which time ranges have been played within the media.